# Debug gwt from inside iframe (X-Frame-Options)

Tags: debugging, google-chrome, gwt, iframe

When I try to debug my gwt app that's inside an iframe (note that gwt codserv and webserv are all local) I'm having permissions issues. The following errors are thrown:

- on Chrome console: "Refused to display document because display
  forbidden by X-Frame-Options.";
- on Chrome webpage window: "Plugin
  failed to connect to Development Mode server at 127.0.0.1:9997 Follow the underlying troubleshooting instructions"

This ONLY happens in Google Chrome, firefox and IE are ok.

I've already searched for simillar problems but all of them are on crossdomain context, and mine is local. Also, tried the proposed solutions but all without success.

Here is an example of my webpage containing my iFrame. I can't debug MyGWT app.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  </head>
  <body>
    <iframe src="MyGWT.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997"></iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The page that's being blocked is probably [TroubleshootingOOPHM](https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/TroubleshootingOOPHM)

FYI, this has been [fixed in GWT 2.5](https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/detail?r=11349), which now links to this page rather than trying to display it in an iframe (moreover underneath the error glasspane, which made it hardly readable anyway before Google changed their server settings)

Comment: You tried to do _what_ exactly? Note that I only answered about your first error message (`X-Frame-Options`); I have no idea about your overall problem though.

Comment: I tried to debug my gwt app that's inside an iframe with gwt 2.5, as you asked. Is very simple, create a simple gwt web project, put it inside an iframe and try debugging at Chrome.

Comment: Exact same errors, in my webpage "Plugin failed to connect..." and when I'm showing javascript console "Refused to display...". I think that this error is related to an security update at Chrome, because it worked. It's been about three months that no longer works.